# Javamail doesn't send email with larger attachments

Tags: java, android, email, jakarta-mail

I want to send an email using Javamail with 2 attachments. One of them is a json file, and the other one is a txt file (logcat.txt). The logcat.txt is about 1mb in size.
It doesn't send any email if I have the `addAttachment(multipart,reportPath,"logcat.txt");` in my code. If I remove `addAttachment(multipart,reportPath,"logcat.txt");` it works.
When the json file gets larger, at one point about 500kb, it doesn't send either.
My code:

```
public synchronized void sendReport(String subject, String body, String filepath, String filename, String reportPath, String sender, String recipients){
    try {
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("mixed"); //try adding "mixed" here as well but it doesn't work
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
        message.setSubject(subject);

        //body
        BodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart2.setText(body);

        Log.d(TAG, "sendReport: " + reportPath);
        //this prints sendReport: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/**app package name**/files/LOG-1472631395.json
        Log.d(TAG, "sendReport: " + filepath);
        //sendReport: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/**app package name**/files/logcat.txt
        addAttachment(multipart,filepath,filename);
        addAttachment(multipart,reportPath,"logcat.txt");
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);

        message.setContent(multipart);

        if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
        else
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));
        Transport.send(message);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void addAttachment(Multipart multipart, String filepath, String filename) throws MessagingException
{
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filepath);
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
}
```

I also use another method to send attachments but it doesn't work either:

```
private static void addAttachment(Multipart multipart, String filepath, String filename) throws Exception
    {
        MimeBodyPart mimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        mimeBodyPart.attachFile(filepath);
        mimeBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
        multipart.addBodyPart(mimeBodyPart);
    }
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does it show any errors in the log?

Comment: @J.Chomel no, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a private mail server of my customer to send emails, and it doesn't show any errors that I can see (because it is a public mail server). I then use Google Mail server, and this is a reply from gmail server to my email account:

> Technical details of permanent failure: Google tried to deliver your
>   message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain
>   mailinator.com by mail2.mailinator.com. [45.79.147.26].
>
> The error that the other server returned was: 552 5.3.4 Message size
>   exceeds fixed limit

So this is because the domain mailinator.com has some message size limit so it doesn't appear. I then send things to a gmail email account and it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
    //In this list set the path from the different files you want to attach
    String[] attachments;

    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

    //Add attachments
    if(attachments != null && attachments.length > 0) {
        for (String str : attachments) {
            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(str);
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            messageBodyPart.setFileName(source.getName());
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        }
    }

    message.setContent(multipart);
```

I don't have problems uploading huge files, you can try this code.